# Generating output text file in R

Tags: r

Firstly my apologies if there is an answer to this query already on stackoverflow but I was unable to find anything!! Essentially I am writing a script in R to (1) process web pages to access the main body of text content, (2) output the results into a formatted text file and (3) perform basic sentiment analysis on the output file.

I am able to generate the text file ok but the formatting of the file is poor for future analysis!

When I run the code `'cat(paste(plain.text, collapse = "\n"))'` where plain.text is the resulting text, it prints the text formatted very neatly to the console. However when I attempt to write the text to a file using the below code, there are white spaces etc which I would like to remove.

```
 test_file <- write(plain.text, file = "test2", append = FALSE,sep = " ")
```

Does anybody know how I might incorporate the `'collapse = "\n"'` code from the cat function into the write function to tidy the formatting?

Thanks a lot
Joe

Comment: not exactly sure what your plain.text looks like, but have you tried using `writeLines(plain.text, con = "test2")` instead of `write`? If that doesn't work, can you add the result of `dput(plain.text)` or part of it to your question?

Comment: please also have to share code how did you scrap the webpage which page, it may be addressed at the step of processing the body text

Comment: For further computer analysis *structure* of the output file is more important than its formatting. Perhaps you could e.g. save it as a csv file (using a function like `write.csv`)